# Can we skip email screen when integrating 'Sign in with Apple' with Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, apple-sign-in

Our team has followed the Azure AD B2C integration with 'Sign in with Apple' using the following official link:
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple

We were able to perform all steps and could see the sign in working seamlessly. But the Apple team has rejected the native app citing the additional Azure B2C screen that asks for email again. As we've selected scope as 'openid email' in Identity Provider configuration, the email address comes pre-filled and user needs to click Continue.

Is there a way to skip the last screen which asks for users to click Continue on pre-filled email address option (check image below)?

The blocker Apple team raised is as follows:

> We continue to find that
> your app requires users to register with personal information that is
> not directly relevant to your app’s core functionality. Specifically,
> the following fields or actions are required but do not appear to be
> directly relevant to your app’s core functionality:
>
> - Your app requires users to input their name and/or email address after using Sign in with Apple.

[image: The image shows the steps taken on the app on clicking Apple icon]

Comment: Hi @Sarabjeet For the sign-up and sign-in flow, for the **User attributes and claims** settings, what happens if you deselect **Collect attribute** for **Email address**? Does that then remove the e-mail address prompt?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett Yes, the removal of email address in User Attributes removes the prompt but the email address is then not passed in claims. The app doesn't function without getting email address.

Comment: @SarabjeetSingh Just make sure in the application claims you have selected the EmailAddress Claim which include the email claim in the token.

Comment: @RohitPrasad Yes, the EmaillAddress claim is checked in application claims. As per the documentation, the following is stated. We're not sure how to workaround from this:


_Note: even if you include the name or email scopes, nether will not be included as claims in the token which Azure AD B2C receives from Apple. Apple provides these values in a non-standard way as part of the authorization response payload. Azure AD B2C will not be able to read these values and you should collect them from the user separately if needed._

Comment: Once you login can you check B2C might have created one account for you. Check on the Graph Explorer and see whether it able to fetch the email or not. 
You mentioned that after login to apple you are getting email value prefilled which means that B2C getting email value from Apple side which helps in prefilled the value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they just don't want you using the email. "We continue to find that your app requires users to register with personal information that is not directly relevant to your app’s core functionality."  appeal their decision and tell them how the email is core part of your functionality.