# Sign in with Apple under Azure B2C requires extra information after signing in

Tags: ios, azure, authentication, azure-ad-b2c

Our app was rejected from the app store due to `Your app requires users to input their name, e-mail address and e-mail verification after using Sign in with Apple`.  We followed the sample online [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/sign-in-with-apple) which clearly states that `even if you include the name or email scopes, nether will not be included as claims in the token which Azure AD B2C receives from Apple`.

We can't remove sign in with Apple either, because then we get `We noticed that your app uses a third-party login service but does not offer Sign in with Apple`.

Thus, we have to be able to sign in with Apple and not show the email screen after signing in.  Is there a way to capture the sign in with Apple email address without showing the email screen after signing in Azure B2C?  I have already looked at similar issues with [no real solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63340383/can-we-skip-email-screen-when-integrating-sign-in-with-apple-with-azure-ad-b2c)

Comment: I could not find a solution to this problem, so we ended up removing 3rd party logins for our app on iOS.